# Service health status doesn't update in azure service fabric explorer from Health Manager?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

My apologies if the question sounds vague. Here is the scenario I observe.

I've created an azure service fabric application (POC) with 2 stateless services.

1. `Service-1` initially reports it's health as **OK** *with a time to live of 5 minutes* in the first iteration and waits for 2 minutes (randomly configured the wait for 2 minutes).
2. 10 seconds later, `Service-2` reports it's health as **Error** *with time to live as 10 **seconds*** in its first iteration. Even this waits for 2 minutes.

At this point, Service fabric explorer correctly shows `Service-1's` status as OK and `Service-2's` status as Error. **AS EXPECTED**.

1. Meanwhile, second iteration of `Service-1` starts and reports it's status now as **ERROR**.
2. Second iteration of **Service-2** also starts and reports its status as **OK** now.

**EXPECTED**: Service fabric explorer would show `Service-1's` status as ERROR and `Service-2's` status as OK.

**ACTUAL** : Both services are being shown as Error.

Doesn't Service fabric explorer get the health status from Health Manager every time it refreshes? If so, why am I being shown the status as Error for both services?

**Code below for reference:**
**Service-1:**

```
long iterations = 0;
if (iterations++%2 == 0)
{
    var healthInformation = new HealthInformation("Service-1", $"{this.Context.ServiceName}-OK-{iterations}-Property",
        HealthState.Ok);
    healthInformation.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
    var healthReport = new StatelessServiceInstanceHealthReport(this.Context.PartitionId,
        this.Context.InstanceId, healthInformation);
    fabricClient.HealthManager.ReportHealth(healthReport);
    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Logged OK health from {0}", this.Context.ServiceName);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), cancellationToken);
}
else
{
    var healthInformation = new HealthInformation("Service-1", $"{this.Context.ServiceName}-Error-{iterations}-Property",
        HealthState.Error);
    healthInformation.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    var healthReport = new StatelessServiceInstanceHealthReport(this.Context.PartitionId,
        this.Context.InstanceId, healthInformation);
    fabricClient.HealthManager.ReportHealth(healthReport);
    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Logged Error health from {0}", this.Context.ServiceName);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), cancellationToken);
}
```

**Service-2:**

```
long iterations = 0;
if (iterations++ % 2 == 0)
{
    var healthInformation = new HealthInformation("StatelessService2", $"{this.Context.ServiceName}-Error-{iterations}-Property",
        HealthState.Error);
    healthInformation.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    var healthReport = new StatelessServiceInstanceHealthReport(this.Context.PartitionId,
        this.Context.InstanceId, healthInformation);
    fabricClient.HealthManager.ReportHealth(healthReport);
    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Logged Error from {0}" , this.Context.ServiceName);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), cancellationToken);
}
else
{
    var healthInformation = new HealthInformation("StatelessService2", $"{this.Context.ServiceName}-OK-{iterations}-Property",
        HealthState.Ok);
    healthInformation.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
    var healthReport = new StatelessServiceInstanceHealthReport(this.Context.PartitionId,
        this.Context.InstanceId, healthInformation);
    fabricClient.HealthManager.ReportHealth(healthReport);
    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Logged OK from {0}" ,this.Context.ServiceName);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the second health property is different from the first health property (since your are naming them based on the iteration), the first health property will remain until its TTL and then have its behavior as defined by the RemoveWhenExpired property (which is false by default, so it will just remain). The first property is not overwritten by the “OK” health report since that is a "different property". In SFX I bet you would actually see both of these properties. They would need to have the same name for this to work the way you’re expecting. More information is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-health-introduction/).

Comment: Got it. I wasn't setting the RemoveWhenExpired property. Thanks for explanation!